# Listado de usuarios por alerta sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

En mi sharepoint 2013 he incorporado un blog donde los trabajadores interesados pueden suscribirse a alertas para recibir notificaciones x nuevas entradas.

Mi pregunta es como poder saber que usuarios se han suscrito a esa alerta.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu pregunta con información sobre lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: El código debe ser introducido como un JavaScript en site ??

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código:

```
public static string listarAlertasLista(SPWeb web, string listaInternalName)
{
    string alerts = "";
    string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + listaInternalName;
    listUrl = listUrl.Replace("//", "/");

    SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
    SPAlertCollection alertsColl = web.Alerts;

    alerts += "<span style='color: blue'>Alertas de la lista " + listaInternalName + "</span><br>";
    foreach (SPAlert alert in alertsColl)
    {
        if (alert.ListID == list.ID)
        {
            alerts += "Usuario: " + alert.User.LoginName + "<br>";
            alerts += "Tipo: " + alert.AlertType + "<br>";
            alerts += "Canales: " + alert.DeliveryChannels.ToString() + "<br>";
        }
    }

    return alerts;
}
```

Comment: El código debe ser introducido en el site como script de Java ?

Comment: Es código C# se debe ejecutar desde el servidor.